# in_array is both true and false

Tags: php, arrays

Odd problem here. I'm writing a simple Hangman game in PHP, and while checking if the letters in the current word matches those guessed, I run in to a problem.

The code is as follows:

```
    $letters = str_split($words[$_SESSION['hangman']['current_word']]);
    foreach($letters as $letter)
    {
        if(in_array($letter, $_SESSION['hangman']['guessed']) == True);
        {
            echo "true for ", $letter , "
";
        }
    }
```

the if-statement will always evaluate to true, even if i change the line to

```
if(in_array($letter, $_SESSION['hangman']['guessed']) == False);
```

Comment: Why would you want to *compare* with truth and falsehood, instead of saying `if (in_array($letter, ...))`?

Comment: I was just testing since it didn't work. The problem was a semicolon at the end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because of the semicolon at the end of your line:

```
if(in_array($letter, $_SESSION['hangman']['guessed']) == False);
```

the semicolon ends the condition; the code after it will always be executed.

Remove the semicolon to make it work as intended.